# Modeling Entity Relationships returns None after save

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

After reading the Modeling Entity Relationship for Python (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling) I went ahead and created some sample code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb, db
from google.appengine.ext.db import polymodel
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

class Car(db.Model):
   brand  =  db.StringProperty(required=True)
   wheels =  db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class Human(db.Model):
    name    = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    drives  = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=Car)
    spouse  = db.SelfReferenceProperty()
    owns    = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class OwnedCar(db.Model):
   brand  =  db.StringProperty(required=True)
   owner  =  db.ReferenceProperty(Human, required=True)

paul = Human(name="Paul")
paul.put()

pauls_bmw = OwnedCar(brand="BMW", owner=paul)
pauls_bmw.put()

pauls_mercedes = OwnedCar(brand="Mercedes", owner=paul)
pauls_mercedes.put()

pauls_cars = paul.ownedcar_set
print "Paul's cars: "
for car in pauls_cars:
    print "- "+car.brand
```

I ran this in the Interactive Console, and to my surprise (since the book shows a similar example), nothing printed out.

Looking into the datastore, I see the data and it's correctly associated. I can also do a quick GQL query to pull the data and print it out in the above manner (which works), but on 'insert/create' the object doesn't have the Reference'd data. Why? How do I make the above work?

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: If you immediately run it again, but query for "Paul", without any of the `put()`s, does the data print?  If so, consistency issue.

Comment: it will be eventual consistancy using a reference set is a query.  Do you have any code in place, if not switch to ndb, reference_sets can be a real pain, and introduce very ineficient datastore access patterns without realizing it, like the loop you have used.

Comment: +1 for switching to [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) if you're just starting something new.

Comment: I agree that NDB would allow me to query the data again and get what I need. The question is why this doesn't have the data in the var, yet this is a book example that can be found in multiple places?